# Is there a way to solve fail to enroll error?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, agent, fleet

I want to install the elastic agent in my host to use my logs in kibana. But when I want to install, this error appears: "fail to enroll: fail to execute request to fleet-server: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".
Please tell me how this problem can be solved.
Thank you in advance
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you encounter is described [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/fleet-troubleshooting.html#agent-enrollment-certs)

To fix this problem you can add the `--insecure` flag when running the installation:

```
> elastic-agent.exe install --insecure
```

Just be aware, however, that by doing you're acknowledging that you understand that the certificate chain cannot be verified. It's ok do this in development but you should not do it in production.